# Upgraded from Studio 19.10 to 20.04, after upgrade cannon mp250 will not print 'error scheduler not running' tried to re-install no good

Tags: upgrade, printing

Have been running Ubuntu Studio 19.10 for over six months on a Dell Optiplex 255 desktop computer. Everything worked,even the scanner on the printer that I never could get to work before.  A message came up that an upgrade to 20.04 was available. I started the upgrade, it seemed to work perfectly, even installed a little faster than projected. It then asked if it was okay to delete no longer needed files or programs. I hesitated a moment before I did this.I now feel that I should have tried out the install before I did this but, I did not. I have the nagging feeling that a needed file was deleted, besides I have plenty of space on the hard drive and would not mind a little trash if it would not affect the operation of the system. Using the 'troubleshooter' I get the message 'Scheduler not running. Scheduler not running object at 0x7f291c3084f0>. Have no idea what this object is nor where it is located. I am 72 years old and not as sharp or quick as I was just ten years ago ( or patient ). Although I have been using various versions of Ubuntu for over four years,I do not consider myself an expert so,keep your answers clear and explain exactly what to do,do not assume that I know all the intermediary steps involved please. Thank You in advance for any help you can provide.